# How do you aggregate initialise a struct with an atomic member?

Tags: c++

Consider

```
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>

struct Foo
{
    std::atomic_int atomic;
};

int main() {
    Foo f{1};
}
```

Fails to compile (gcc, C++14) with error

```
error: use of deleted function ‘std::atomic<int>::atomic(const std::atomic<int>&)’
```

(Note that MSVC compiles the code.)

Comment: I think your code should work as of C++17. For C++11 or C++14, see the duplicate. TLDR; `Foo f{{1}};` should work.